# Extremely slow import of mx files with Molecule objects

Tags: import, chemistry

Version: 13.0.1 on Linux

Hello,

I recently found a collection of 39,361 SMILES strings that I converted to Molecule format with Mathematica. I then exported the resulting list of Molecule objects into a .mx file and tried to import using Import. However, the import operation takes more than an hour to finish. This seems extremely slow, I wonder if other folks have similar experiences with importing Molecule objects. Is there a way/format to export Molecule data so that the import may be faster?

The collection of SMILES strings is provided [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/8588407c-325e-442b-befa-1269d66f601b)

The mx file in question is provided here [mx file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rribuo1wbilyozw/molecules.mx?dl=0)

In general, I have found that large collections of Molecule objects in a .mx file take a long time to import. Perhaps, there's a better way to work with large collections of Molecules. I am looking for any advice or recommendation from the community.

Thanks,

Comment: I find that I can import your MX file in about 200 milliseconds.  Does the time you see for importing change if you put a semicolon at the end of your code?  Typesetting 40k molecules could take some time

Comment: Wow! I did not realize that it was not the actual Import, but the display that was the bottleneck. Thanks a lot! With the suppressed output, the import is essentially instantaneous on my system as well. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately formatting for molecule objects is unreasonably slow, which is what causes the issue you see.

So reading the molecules from disk

```
In[16]:= temp = Import["molecules.mx"]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[16]= {0.192292, Null}
```

but displaying them is slow

```
In[17]:= 
boxes = Map[MakeBoxes[#, StandardForm] &, 
    temp[[;; 1000]]]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[17]= {67.4213, Null}
```

This number really should be a lot lower. If you set the variable `` Chemistry`Private`$FormatMolecules = True `` it will take only a third of the time, but still long enough that you don't want to run it forty thousand times if you can avoid it.